# In topology, what is the name for these closed sets?

Tags: general-topology

Let $T$ be a topological space over $X$.

Call a closed set $G$ *informative at point* $a$ iff

1. $G$ is a *proper* subset of $X$, i.e., $G\subset X$, and,
2. there exists a closed set $G'$ with $a\in G'\subset G$, i.e., $G'$ is a *proper* subset of $G$.

- Is there a (well-known/known) name for these closed sets?

Of course the informative closed sets are *almost* all closed sets.

If it makes a difference, I only use this notion with effect for symmetric spaces ($R_0$). In a $T_1$ space the non-informative sets can be "thrown away", since they are trivially "known". In a symmetric space, if a closed set if informative at a point it is informative at all it's points: sort of like an *open* set!

It is my suspicion that topologists who work with symmetric spaces might know these closed sets.

Comment: When you say *symmetric space*, do you mean an $R_0$ space (Kolmogorov quotient is $T_1$)?

Comment: Yes. $R_0$ and when factored $T_1$

Comment: I updated the OP.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is a name for such notion, but for usual space the proposed notion is quite trivial.

Namely, for any $a\in X$ denote by $cl(a)$ its closure. So, any closed $G$ containing $a$, also contains $cl(a)$. Therefore $G\subset X$ is *informative* if and only if is different from $cl(a)$.

For $T_1$ spaces, where points are closed, this reduces to say that a propre closed subset $G\subset X$ is *informative* at $a$ if and only if it contains $a$ and at least onother point.

Comment: Yes, in a symmetric space these are almost all closed sets, but *not quite*. And that is key in my construction I am working on. In a T1 space you can "throw away" the non-informative closed sets because they are "known".

Comment: I am thinking that those who work with symmetric spaces might know these closed sets?